# How to calcuate the overlap date in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data with users who has worked with multiple companies.Some users who worked in more than one companies at the same time. How to aggregate the overall experience without considering overlap experience.
I have gone through some of the links could get right solutions.Any help will appreciated.

***EMP CSV DATA***

```
fullName,Experience_datesEmployeed,Experience_expcompany,Experience_expduraation, Experience_position
David,Feb 1999 - Sep 2001, Foothill,2 yrs 8 mos, Marketing Assoicate
David,1994 - 1997, abc,3 yrs,Senior Auditor
David,Jun 2020 - Present,   Fellows INC,3 mos,Director Board
David,2017 - Jun 2019,     Fellows INC ,2 yrs,Fellow - Class 22
David,Sep 2001 - Present, The John D.,19 yrs, Manager
```

***Expected output:***

```
FullName,Total_Experience

David,24.8 yrs
```

Comment: I think you will need to create a `UDAF` (user defined aggregate function) as the requirement is very specific.  You need to sort all `Experience_dates` for a user based on `end_date` (**why?** search `non-overlapping intervals` problem) then do a kind of running window sum like (exprience_a + experience_b = end_b - start_a if they overlap else (end_a - start_a) + (end_b - start_b)!

Comment: any reference link or pseudo code please